# Any tips on how to integrate the code block

Tags: vb.net

What I want to happen is this, when I entered a number and if that number is  1, this will display "Item Successfully Sendout, Quantity is 1" and If I entered a letter it should be an error.

```vb
If IsNumeric(SendOutQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
    If SendOutQuantityTxtBx.Text <= 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Item Successfully Sendout, Quantity is 1")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Not a number")
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity above 1")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Try moving your MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Not a number") to before last end if and add else before hand.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`, correct the errors and try again. Also, see whether that number must be 1 or it can actually be less than 1 to be a valid input.

Comment: @Mukyuu yea I did, just some sort of mishaps in the coding. Anyway thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

You need to put and else before last end if, in order to manage what happens if text is not numeric.

```
If IsNumeric(SendOutQuantityTxtBx.Text) Then
    If SendOutQuantityTxtBx.Text <= 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Item Successfully Sendout, Quantity is 1")
    Else        
        MessageBox.Show("Quantity above 1")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: Not a number")
End If
```